# JavaFX Tic-Tac-Toe Game

Tags: java, game, tic-tac-toe, javafx

I programmed a Tic Tac Toe game using JavaFX, and I'm looking for a code review of it to improve my skills and practices in Java. It would highly be appreciated if you reviewers emphasize on these points specifically:

- Bad practices which I am following
- Inefficiencies and how would I rectify them

**TicTacToe.java:**

```
package tictactoe;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TicTacToe extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("TicTacToe.fxml"));

        stage.setTitle("TicTacToe by Hassan Althaf");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**TicTacToeController.java:**

```
package tictactoe;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class TicTacToeController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Circle CircleOne;

    @FXML
    private Circle CircleTwo;

    @FXML
    private Circle CircleThree;

    @FXML
    private Circle CircleFour;

    @FXML
    private Circle CircleFive;

    @FXML
    private Circle CircleSix;

    @FXML
    private Circle CircleSeven;

    @FXML
    private Circle CircleEight;

    @FXML
    private Circle CircleNine;

    @FXML
    private Label XOne;

    @FXML
    private Label XTwo;

    @FXML
    private Label XThree;

    @FXML
    private Label XFour;

    @FXML
    private Label XFive;

    @FXML
    private Label XSix;

    @FXML
    private Label XSeven;

    @FXML
    private Label XEight;

    @FXML
    private Label XNine;

    @FXML
    private Label lblMessages;

    private int[] filledSquares = new int[9];
    private int[] filledCircles = new int[5];
    private int[] filledX = new int[5];

    private int filledSquaresCounter = 0;
    private int filledCirclesCounter = 0;
    private int filledXCounter = 0;

    private char winningTeam;

    final private int[][] winningPositions = {
        {1, 5, 9},
        {3, 5, 7},
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6},
        {7, 8, 9},
        {1, 4, 7},
        {2, 5, 8},
        {3, 6, 9}
    };

    private boolean allowMoves = true;

    private boolean tie = false;

    @FXML
    public void handleSquareOneClick(MouseEvent event) {
        this.handleSquareClick(1);
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleSquareTwoClick(MouseEvent event) {
        this.handleSquareClick(2);
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleSquareThreeClick(MouseEvent event) {
        this.handleSquareClick(3);
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleSquareFourClick(MouseEvent event) {
        this.handleSquareClick(4);
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleSquareFiveClick(MouseEvent event) {
        this.handleSquareClick(5);
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleSquareSixClick(MouseEvent event) {
        this.handleSquareClick(6);
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleSquareSevenClick(MouseEvent event) {
        this.handleSquareClick(7);
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleSquareEightClick(MouseEvent event) {
        this.handleSquareClick(8);
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleSquareNineClick(MouseEvent event) {
        this.handleSquareClick(9);
    }

    public void handleSquareClick(int squareNumber) {
        if(!isAlreadySelectedBox(squareNumber) && this.allowMoves == true) {
            switch(squareNumber) {
                case 1:
                    this.showCircleOne();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    this.showCircleTwo();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    this.showCircleThree();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    this.showCircleFour();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    this.showCircleFive();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    this.showCircleSix();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    this.showCircleSeven();
                    break;    
                case 8:
                    this.showCircleEight();
                    break;
                case 9:
                    this.showCircleNine();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Impossible choice");
                    break;
            }

            this.filledSquares[this.filledSquaresCounter] = squareNumber;
            this.filledCircles[this.filledCirclesCounter] = squareNumber;
            this.filledSquaresCounter++;
            this.filledCirclesCounter++;

            if(this.checkVictory()) {
                this.endGame();
            } else {
                this.playRandomMove();

                if(this.checkVictory()) {
                    this.endGame();
                }
            }
        } else if(this.filledSquaresCounter >= 9) {
            this.tie = true;
            this.endGame();
        }
    }

    public boolean isAlreadySelectedBox(int squareNumber) {
        boolean found = false;

        for(int filledSquare : this.filledSquares) {
            if(squareNumber == filledSquare) {
                found = true;
            }
        }

        return found == true;
    }

    public boolean checkVictory() {
        if(this.filledCirclesCounter < 3 && this.filledXCounter < 3) {
            return false;
        }

        for(int[] filled : this.winningPositions) {
            int slotCounter = 0;

            for(int singleFilled : filled) {
                if(this.isOccupiedByCircle(singleFilled)) {
                    slotCounter++;
                }
            }

            if(slotCounter == 3) {
                this.winningTeam = 'O';
                this.allowMoves = false;
                return true;
            }

            slotCounter = 0;

            for(int singleFilled : filled) {
                if(this.isOccupiedByX(singleFilled)) {
                    slotCounter++;
                }
            }

            if(slotCounter == 3) {
                this.winningTeam = 'X';
                this.allowMoves = false;
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void showCircleOne() {
        this.CircleOne.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void showCircleTwo() {
        this.CircleTwo.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void showCircleThree() {
        this.CircleThree.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void showCircleFour() {
        this.CircleFour.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void showCircleFive() {
        this.CircleFive.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void showCircleSix() {
        this.CircleSix.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void showCircleSeven() {
        this.CircleSeven.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void showCircleEight() {
        this.CircleEight.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void showCircleNine() {
        this.CircleNine.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void playRandomMove() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int result = random.nextInt(9 - 1 + 1) + 1;;

        if(this.filledSquaresCounter < 9) {
            while(this.isAlreadySelectedBox(result)) {
                result = random.nextInt(9 - 1 + 1) + 1;
            }

            switch(result) {
                case 1:
                    this.showXOne();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    this.showXTwo();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    this.showXThree();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    this.showXFour();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    this.showXFive();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    this.showXSix();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    this.showXSeven();
                    break;    
                case 8:
                    this.showXEight();
                    break;
                case 9:
                    this.showXNine();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Impossible choice");
                    break;
            }

            this.filledSquares[this.filledSquaresCounter] = result;
            this.filledX[this.filledXCounter] = result;
            this.filledSquaresCounter++;
            this.filledXCounter++;
        } else {
            this.tie = true;
            this.endGame();
        }


    }

    public void showXOne() {
        this.XOne.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void showXTwo() {
        this.XTwo.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void showXThree() {
        this.XThree.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void showXFour() {
        this.XFour.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void showXFive() {
        this.XFive.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void showXSix() {
        this.XSix.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void showXSeven() {
        this.XSeven.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void showXEight() {
        this.XEight.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void showXNine() {
        this.XNine.setVisible(true);
    }

    public boolean isOccupiedByCircle(int circlePosition) {
        boolean found = false;

        for(int filledCircle : this.filledCircles) {
            if(filledCircle == circlePosition) {
                found = true;
            }
        }

        return found == true;
    }

    public boolean isOccupiedByX(int xPosition) {
        boolean found = false;

        for(int filled : this.filledX) {
            if(filled == xPosition) {
                found = true;
            }
        }

        return found == true;
    }

    public void endGame() {
        this.allowMoves = false;

        if(this.tie == true) {
            this.lblMessages.setText("It was a tie!");
        } else if(String.valueOf(this.winningTeam).equals("O")) {
            this.lblMessages.setText("You win!");
        } else if(String.valueOf(this.winningTeam).equals("X")) {
            this.lblMessages.setText("Sorry, you lose!");
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleResetButton(ActionEvent event) {
        this.CircleOne.setVisible(false);
        this.CircleTwo.setVisible(false);
        this.CircleThree.setVisible(false);
        this.CircleFour.setVisible(false);
        this.CircleFive.setVisible(false);
        this.CircleSix.setVisible(false);
        this.CircleSeven.setVisible(false);
        this.CircleEight.setVisible(false);
        this.CircleNine.setVisible(false);

        this.XOne.setVisible(false);
        this.XTwo.setVisible(false);
        this.XThree.setVisible(false);
        this.XFour.setVisible(false);
        this.XFive.setVisible(false);
        this.XSix.setVisible(false);
        this.XSeven.setVisible(false);
        this.XEight.setVisible(false);
        this.XNine.setVisible(false);

        this.winningTeam = 0;

        this.allowMoves = true;
        this.tie = false;

        this.lblMessages.setText("");

        this.filledSquares = new int[9];
        this.filledCircles = new int[5];
        this.filledX = new int[5];

        this.filledSquaresCounter = 0;
        this.filledCirclesCounter = 0;
        this.filledXCounter = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

**TicTacToe.fxml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="450.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="tictactoe.TicTacToeController">
   <children>
      <Line endX="150.0" layoutX="300.0" layoutY="150.0" startX="-150.0" />
      <Line endY="150.0" layoutX="250.0" layoutY="200.0" startY="-150.0" />
      <Line endY="150.0" layoutX="350.0" layoutY="200.0" startY="-150.0" />
      <Line endX="150.0" layoutX="300.0" layoutY="250.0" startX="-150.0" />
      <Rectangle fx:id="SquareOne" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="WHITE" height="98.0" layoutX="151.0" layoutY="51.0" onMouseClicked="#handleSquareOneClick" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="98.0" />
      <Rectangle fx:id="SquareTwo" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="WHITE" height="98.0" layoutX="251.0" layoutY="50.0" onMouseClicked="#handleSquareTwoClick" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="98.0" />
      <Rectangle fx:id="SquareThree" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="WHITE" height="98.0" layoutX="351.0" layoutY="51.0" onMouseClicked="#handleSquareThreeClick" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="98.0" />
      <Rectangle fx:id="SquareFour" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="WHITE" height="98.0" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="151.0" onMouseClicked="#handleSquareFourClick" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="98.0" />
      <Rectangle fx:id="SquareFive" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="WHITE" height="98.0" layoutX="251.0" layoutY="151.0" onMouseClicked="#handleSquareFiveClick" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="98.0" />
      <Rectangle fx:id="SquareSix" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="WHITE" height="98.0" layoutX="351.0" layoutY="151.0" onMouseClicked="#handleSquareSixClick" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="98.0" />
      <Rectangle fx:id="SquareSeven" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="WHITE" height="98.0" layoutX="151.0" layoutY="251.0" onMouseClicked="#handleSquareSevenClick" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="98.0" />
      <Rectangle fx:id="SquareEight" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="WHITE" height="98.0" layoutX="251.0" layoutY="251.0" onMouseClicked="#handleSquareEightClick" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="98.0" />
      <Rectangle fx:id="SquareNine" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="WHITE" height="98.0" layoutX="351.0" layoutY="251.0" onMouseClicked="#handleSquareNineClick" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="98.0" />
      <Circle fx:id="CircleOne" fill="WHITE" layoutX="200.0" layoutY="99.0" radius="48.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="8.0" visible="false" />
      <Circle fx:id="CircleTwo" fill="WHITE" layoutX="300.0" layoutY="99.0" radius="48.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="8.0" visible="false" />
      <Circle fx:id="CircleThree" fill="WHITE" layoutX="400.0" layoutY="100.0" radius="48.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="8.0" visible="false" />
      <Circle fx:id="CircleFour" fill="WHITE" layoutX="200.0" layoutY="200.0" radius="48.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="8.0" visible="false" />
      <Circle fx:id="CircleFive" fill="WHITE" layoutX="300.0" layoutY="200.0" radius="48.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="8.0" visible="false" />
      <Circle fx:id="CircleSix" fill="WHITE" layoutX="400.0" layoutY="200.0" radius="48.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="8.0" visible="false" />
      <Circle fx:id="CircleSeven" fill="WHITE" layoutX="200.0" layoutY="300.0" radius="48.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="8.0" visible="false" />
      <Circle fx:id="CircleEight" fill="WHITE" layoutX="300.0" layoutY="300.0" radius="48.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="8.0" visible="false" />
      <Circle fx:id="CircleNine" fill="WHITE" layoutX="400.0" layoutY="300.0" radius="48.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="8.0" visible="false" />
      <Label fx:id="XOne" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="151.0" layoutY="50.0" maxHeight="98.0" maxWidth="98.0" minHeight="98.0" minWidth="98.0" prefHeight="98.0" prefWidth="98.0" text="X" visible="false">
         <font>
            <Font size="88.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="XTwo" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="251.0" layoutY="51.0" maxHeight="98.0" maxWidth="98.0" minHeight="98.0" minWidth="98.0" prefHeight="98.0" prefWidth="98.0" text="X" visible="false">
         <font>
            <Font size="88.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="XThree" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="351.0" layoutY="50.0" maxHeight="98.0" maxWidth="98.0" minHeight="98.0" minWidth="98.0" prefHeight="98.0" prefWidth="98.0" text="X" visible="false">
         <font>
            <Font size="88.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="XFour" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="151.0" layoutY="151.0" maxHeight="98.0" maxWidth="98.0" minHeight="98.0" minWidth="98.0" prefHeight="98.0" prefWidth="98.0" text="X" visible="false">
         <font>
            <Font size="88.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="XFive" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="251.0" layoutY="152.0" maxHeight="98.0" maxWidth="98.0" minHeight="98.0" minWidth="98.0" prefHeight="98.0" prefWidth="98.0" text="X" visible="false">
         <font>
            <Font size="88.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="XSix" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="351.0" layoutY="151.0" maxHeight="98.0" maxWidth="98.0" minHeight="98.0" minWidth="98.0" prefHeight="98.0" prefWidth="98.0" text="X" visible="false">
         <font>
            <Font size="88.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="XSeven" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="151.0" layoutY="251.0" maxHeight="98.0" maxWidth="98.0" minHeight="98.0" minWidth="98.0" prefHeight="98.0" prefWidth="98.0" text="X" visible="false">
         <font>
            <Font size="88.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="XEight" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="251.0" layoutY="251.0" maxHeight="98.0" maxWidth="98.0" minHeight="98.0" minWidth="98.0" prefHeight="98.0" prefWidth="98.0" text="X" visible="false">
         <font>
            <Font size="88.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="XNine" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="351.0" layoutY="251.0" maxHeight="98.0" maxWidth="98.0" minHeight="98.0" minWidth="98.0" prefHeight="98.0" prefWidth="98.0" text="X" visible="false">
         <font>
            <Font size="88.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="lblMessages" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="366.0" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="300.0">
         <font>
            <Font size="16.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button fx:id="btnReset" layoutX="274.0" layoutY="398.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleResetButton" text="Reset" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 8):

### View

It was a lucky choice to implement tic-tac-toa and not e.g. go. With `circleOne` to `circleThreeHundredAndSixtyOne` it could get rather lengthy.

You can see what I dislike most. Starting with the [XML abuse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/647746/581205)(*), the repetitiveness propagates everywhere.

Maybe FXML allows arrays and loops, which could shorten your XML. But then we get to another point, namely [XML programing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/646987/581205):

> There's only one thing worse than people claiming they program in XML, and that's people who actually program in XML. See ANT for examples.

---

Your FXML has at least one tiny bug, namely the y-coordinates 99 and 100.

```
  <Circle fx:id="CircleTwo" fill="WHITE" layoutX="300.0" layoutY="99.0" radius="48.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="8.0" visible="false" />
  <Circle fx:id="CircleThree" fill="WHITE" layoutX="400.0" layoutY="100.0" radius="48.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="8.0" visible="false" />
```

---

### Model

You have a view (the FXML), a controller, but no model. A model is something what stores the whole game state and is completely independent of the GUI. Having a model has only advantages

- testability: You can test if the game logic works automatically.
- flexibility: You can save the model in a file, you can send it over network. You can plug in a network player or an AI.
- [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns): The code gets much cleaner.

### Controller

```
 private Circle CircleOne;
```

According to Java conventions, variable names start lowercase. I'd go for `circle1`, as the suffix "One" gives you nothing besides looking better.

```
private int[] filledSquares = new int[9];
private int[] filledCircles = new int[5];
private int[] filledX = new int[5];
```

No idea, what this is about. Why are there just 5 of them? Maybe because of the game taking at most 9 plies, i.e., 5 moves? You should use constants (or comments) making it clear.

---

```
@FXML
public void handleSquareOneClick(MouseEvent event) {
    this.handleSquareClick(1);
}

...

public void handleSquareClick(int squareNumber) {
    if(!isAlreadySelectedBox(squareNumber) && this.allowMoves == true) {
        switch(squareNumber) {
            case 1:
                this.showCircleOne();
                break;

....

public void showCircleNine() {
    this.CircleNine.setVisible(true);
}

...

public void showCircleOne() {
    this.CircleOne.setVisible(true);
}

...

public void showXNine() {
    this.XOne.setVisible(true);
}
```

So due to the FXML, every single thing is repeated 9 or 18 times. You need 36 trivial methods, a complicated switch and you repeat and repeat and repeat....

Have I said already that the repetitive XML leads to repetitive code?

Have I said already that the repetitive XML leads to repetitive code?

Have I said already that the repetitive XML leads to repetitive code?

---

(*) YMMV, but usually, all these "declarativeness" means actually "verbosity and repetitiveness". IMHO, arrays, loops, and a [good layout manager](http://www.miglayout.com) is the way to go. It works for Java FX, too. For tic-tac-toe, `GridLayout` is surely good enough, see my [ultimatoe](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/96015/ultimatoe-1-gui-and-general-game-interfaces).

## Practical advice

As you can see, I wouldn't use any FXML. YMMV, but in any case, use arrays, loops, and general methods.

```
private final Circle[] circles = {circle1, circle2, ..., circle9};
```

Replace all the `handleSquareXxxClick` by

```
public void handleSquareClick(MouseEvent event) {
     handleSquareClick(circles.indexOf(event.getSource());
}
```

(you may need to adapt it a bit to what really is the click source).

```
public void handleSquareClick(int squareNumber) {
    if(!isAlreadySelectedBox(squareNumber) && this.allowMoves == true) {
        circles[squareNumber].setVisible(true);
        ...
```

I can see I was a bit wrong, there's something like a model, namely `filledSquares` and `filledCircles`, but that's more useful for the history than for finding out the current state. Instead of

```
public boolean isAlreadySelectedBox(int squareNumber) {
    boolean found = false;

    for(int filledSquare : this.filledSquares) {
        if(squareNumber == filledSquare) {
            found = true;
        }
    }

    return found == true;
}
```

which btw. could be simplified to

```
public boolean isAlreadySelectedBox(int squareNumber) {
    for(int filledSquare : this.filledSquares) {
        if(squareNumber == filledSquare) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

you could have

```
private final boolean[] squareIsFilled = new boolean[9];
```

and set `squareIsFilled[squareNumber] = true` in `handleSquareClick`.

Or possibly better, use

```
enum FieldState {EMPTY, CIRCLE, CROSS}
private final FieldState fieldStates = new FieldState[9];
```

to keep all needed information in a single array.

*Whatever you do, you should aim at making the code less repetitive as in the current state it's hard to see anything.*

### My personal rules

- before copying anything, think about a different solution (that's sometimes hard, but still easier than a later de-duplication)
- always make a gui-free part (create a class called `Model` and put in everything you can)

### Example Model

```
class Model {
    private int turn;
    private final FieldState fieldStates = new FieldState[9];

    public boolean canPlay(int index) ...
    public void play(int index) ...
    public boolean isDecided() ...
    public FieldState getWinner() ...
}
```

Comment: @maaartinus public .indexOf doesn't seem to work. it says no such method.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf Sorry, I forgot it's an array and no `List`. Switch to it or use `Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(whatever)`.

Comment: @maaartinus I've implemented *most* of the stuff you mentioned, but I cannot seem to implement the MVC pattern in JavaFX. Any recommended resources I could refer to? Also, I have posted a new question onto how to improve the code again.

Answer (score 4):

- Put the Circle and Label objects in arrays so you don't need all
  those "showCircleNumber()" methods.
- The Random object should be class-level.  It should only be created once

The way you are returning booleans in the `isOccupiedByX` and `isOccupiedByCircle` methods is over-complicated

```
public boolean isOccupiedByX(int xPosition) {
    for(int filled : this.filledX) {
        if(filled == xPosition) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Various assignments are abundant and should be simplified for readability. For example:

```
int result = random.nextInt(9 - 1 + 1) + 1;;
```

There are two semicolons where one should be removed, and `9 - 1 + 1` evaluates into `9`. That should be used instead for the parameter.

Conditional statements like `found == true` and `this.tie == true` performs an unnecessary comparison. They can be used on their own: `return found;`.